# Rails - String concatenation issue while processing an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, concatenation

I am trying to process the results of an array into a string to pass for a search. I want to build a string from the array that would look something like

> ("categories.name like '%Forms%' or categories.name like '%Apples%'")

```
   serialize :category, JSON
 if category.count > 1 && category.index != 0
           $search_global.category.each do |cat_name|
                      cat_name.slice '" '
                      # cat_name
                      $array_count = $array_count + 1
                      if cat_name != ''
                        $inside_count = $inside_count +1
                        $cat_name_2 = "categories.name like %" + $cat_name_2 + cat_name + "% or " + $inside_count.to_s

                      end
            end

  end
```

If I select one item, it works fine as in

> categories.name like %Forms% or 1

Please note that I am including the inside count just to get a better idea of what is happening.

The problem I have is when I select 2 or more items. `categories.name like %` is repeated twice and then the array items or listed as in

> categories.name like %categories.name like %Calendar% or 1Forms% or 2

I can't seem to figure out why the concatenation isn't working as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$cat_name_2 = "categories.name like %" + $cat_name_2 + cat_name + "% or " + $inside_count.to_s
```

Your are using $cat_name_2 as the asignee as well as inside the assignment statement.